# dlopen error "unsafe use of relative rpath" on OS X El Capitan

Tags: python, c++, macos, cmake, swig

I have been developing two C++ libraries which are built by CMake. One of the libraries (ProjectB) has a Python wrapper generated by SWIG, which is dependent on the other library (ProjectA).

These libraries work fine on Linux and OS X Yosemite or earlier. But I get the following error when I import the Python wrapper of ProjectB on El Capitan.

```
 $ python
 >>> import project_b
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "project_b.py", line 28, in <module>
    _project_b = swig_import_helper()
  File "project_b.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_project_b', fp, pathname, description)
 ImportError: dlopen(./_project_b.so, 2): Library not loaded: libProjectA.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/oxon/cmake_test/ProjectB_build/_project_b.so
  Reason: unsafe use of relative rpath libProjectA.dylib in ./_project_b.so with restricted binary
```

I think this is related to the new security technology of El Capitan, and dynamic libraries installed under `/usr/local/lib` cannot be loaded if they are called by a relative path. Indeed, `otool -L` shows that my Python wrapper (`_project_b.so`) has a relative path to ProjectA (`libProjectA.dylib` which is installed under `/usr/local/lib`).

```
 $ otool -L _project_b.so 
_project_b.so:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.10)
    libProjectA.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
```

**Question**: I would like to know how to fix this error by modifying my CMakeLists.txt in these project. How can I link `libProjectA.dylib` by absolute path?

I know that the `install_name_tool` command can change a relative path to an absolute path. But I do not want to ask the users of my libraries to do it every time. So I would like to fix this issue in CMakeLists.txt.

`ProjectB/exeB`, however, works OK without the rpath issue even though it also uses `libProjectB.dylib` and `libProjectA.dylib`.

---

Here is the directory structure of ProjectA,

```
ProjectA
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── ProjectAConfig.cmake
├── include
│   └── ProjectA
│       └── MyClassA.h
└── src
    └── MyClassA.cxx
```

and of ProjectB.

```
ProjectB
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── exeB.cxx
├── include
│   └── ProjectB
│       └── MyClassB.h
├── project_b.i
└── src
    └── MyClassB.cxx
```

I did the build process with the following steps.

```
$ pwd
/Users/oxon/cmake_test
$ ls
ProjectA       ProjectA_build ProjectB       ProjectB_build
$ cd ProjectA_build
$ cmake ../ProjectA
$ make
$ sudo make install
$ cd ../ProjectB_build
$ cmake ../ProjectB
$ make
$ python
>>> import project_b
```

You can download my minimum examples from
https://github.com/akira-okumura/stackoverflow_question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the following lines in `ProjectB/CMakeLists.txt` has fixed the issue.

```
if(APPLE)
  set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH TRUE)

# The following settings were copied from
# https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling
# to avoid the rpath issue that appears on OS X El Capitan

  # use, i.e. don't skip the full RPATH for the build tree
  set(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH  FALSE)

  # when building, don't use the install RPATH already
  # (but later on when installing)
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE) # Changed to TRUE by A.O. 

  set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib")

  # add the automatically determined parts of the RPATH
  # which point to directories outside the build tree to the install RPATH
  set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)

  # the RPATH to be used when installing, but only if it's not a system directory
  list(FIND CMAKE_PLATFORM_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib" isSystemDir)
  if("${isSystemDir}" STREQUAL "-1")
     set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib")
  endif("${isSystemDir}" STREQUAL "-1")
endif()
```

The `CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH` option was changed from `FALSE` to `TRUE` to allow the user to test `import project_b` under the build directory before installing the ProjectB library.